# Cost of tape backup in 1980

Tags: history, magnetic-tape

How much did it cost in 1980 to buy a tape drive capable of backing up 5 megabytes of data? Both for the drive itself and per tape?

(If that exact data is unavailable, I'd be interested in something close, e.g. prices from a couple of years earlier, or storage within an order of magnitude of 5 megabytes.)

Comment: Well, it could be as cheap as a cassette deck attached to a personal computer of the time and as many cassettes as needed to hold 5 megabytes of data.

Comment: @RossRidge We geeks can poke a hole in any question, can't we? :-) Okay: five megabytes *per tape* because human nature being what it is, a backup procedure that involves repeated manual changes of tape, won't get done.

Comment: My back-of-beermat calculation reckons that 5MB would easily fit onto a C120 at 1500 baud. Good luck reliably restoring the data off such thin tape though!

Comment: Your 5Mb storage requirement is rather small for the 1980s. In 1972, 3M was already marketing 20Mb quarter-inch tape cartridges. By 1984, the IBM 3480 had 200Mb capacity.

Comment: This page http://www.hpmuseum.net/display_item.php?hw=258 gives the cost of a 133Mb tape system in 1988 as $3980. Maybe not close enough to "5Mb in 1980" to answer the OP's question, though.

Comment: Details of several other HP tape products on the links from http://www.hpmuseum.net/exhibit.php?class=4&cat=85

Comment: @alephzero I don't think the first 3M QIC tape format was anywhere near 20Mb. The QIC-11 20MB format is a 4 track format, and the first QIC drives were single track. According to Wikipedia "The original product, the DC300, has 300 feet of tape and holds 200 kilobytes". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarter-inch_cartridge

Comment: @rwallace I'd almost come somewhere near working out how many Type I tapes would be needed... :-( Serves me right for not refreshing.

Comment: @pndc are you sure you calculated bits per second and not bytes per second on your beermat?

Comment: @Tommy I re-calculated and see my error: I cheekily went for storing data on all four audio tracks, but erroneously put 120 minutes *per side* rather than in total. Trying to get 5MB on a C120 would require *3,000 baud* in stereo, which is probably beyond the technology.

Comment: @RossRidge "The original product, the DC300, has 300 feet of tape and holds 200 kilobytes" - and the next line of that web page says "QIC-11: a four-track format giving 20 MB on a 450 ft DC300XL cartridge" - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tape_drive for the date.

Comment: @alephzero Yes, I'm saying the QIC-11 20MB format didn't exist in 1972, as it's a multi-track "serpentine" recording format that QIC drives didn't support originally.

Comment: @RossRidge my QIC drive information came from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tape_drive#History which implies it did exist in 1972. I don't have any first-hand knowledge to offer, though.

Comment: @alephzero I believe it's an error. The QIC-11 format wasn't the first tape format for 3M's quarter inch tape cartridges. It was the first though to become sort of a *de facto* standard for the medium. Several tape drives used it but they weren't always compatible with each other. That problem appears to led to the formation of the Working Group for Quarter-Inch Cartridge Drive Compatibility in 1982 which produced the first QIC standards and is where the name QIC comes from. See note 9 under "Notes about SLR media and formats" in http://www.3480-3590-data-conversion.com/media-dc6000.html

Comment: I'm sure I saw domestic VHS recorders used for backup in maybe 1982-1985 sort of era. No idea about the capacity (or cost).

Comment: if you look through the ads in Byte magazine you should find some information. Looks like they don't have 1980, but 1979 and 1981 are there. You can find PDFs of the magazines at https://archive.org/details/byte-magazine?and%5B%5D=year%3A%221979%22&and%5B%5D=year%3A%221981%22

Comment: @SeanHoulihane I recall watching a TV documentary that mentioned VHS tapes being used to transfer data recorded at radio telescopes by astronomers. I don't recall which exact telescope or which era it was from, though.

Comment: I'm not sure what tape backups cost then, because backups that size worked quite well using floppy disks.  Depending on where in the world you are, and the size of the diskettes, figure $10 to $100 US per box of ten diskettes, and a capabity of between 80 and 360 kB/diskette, so a few tens of dollars to a couple of hundred dollars, not counting the cost of the floppy drives.  (Ideally you'd want two floppy drives to make this faster and easier - backup software usually alternated between drives in this case - but you could do it on a single drive as well.)

Answer (score 1):

> How much did it cost in 1980 to buy a tape drive capable of backing up 5 megabytes of data? Both for the drive itself and per tape?

The biggest issue here might be that in 1980 most users didn't have hard drives. Mind you, Tandy was at that time selling the Model II withoug hard disk, but 1-4 floppies as professional system. Even the lowest cost hard disk setup in 1980 was still way past 3000 USD, with the drive alone being way past 2000 USD - a well fited S100 system including a floppy would cost less.

A Corvus S100 HD subsystem would be close to [5000 USD](https://archive.org/stream/byte-magazine-1980-12/1980_12_BYTE_05-12_Adventure#page/n155) - which isinteresting here, as Corvus already offered a tape backup solution in1980, the [Mirror Backup System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corvus_Systems#Disk_drives_and_backup), which could use a standard VCR to backup the harddrive. Several full backups could be made onto a single standard tape. This added another 800 USD for the option plus ~1000 USD for a VCR. Compared with a professional QIC backup system a real bargain.

So if one had already bought a Corvus disk system, **adding backup would be somewhat less than 2,000 USD. Tape cost was that of a simple VCR cassette, less than 10 USD.**

Comment: It may well be because I was on Betamax, but my memory suggests that video cassettes cost somewhat more than USD $10 (= GBP £4.70 or more depending on precisely when you changed the currency) in 1980.

Answer (score 0):

Your question implies "proper" tape storage, which would have been prohibitive for most computer users back then. Other answers give plausible price estimates for dedicated data tape products.

However, back then, the home computers that us peasants could actually afford often had *only* audio cassette tape as their storage medium. At a typical 1200 baud, 5MB is around 12 hours of tape, so a dozen or so C60s would suffice. Actually attempting to perform such a backup would be an exercise in boredom and frustration though. In practice, one would (or at least should) just save twice to two different tapes when creating the data in the first place.

I recall that tape recorders were a few tens of pounds and tapes about a pound each. These prices would vary wildly depending on quality. You perhaps don't want to do anything business critical with those 5 for £2 tapes.